# U2F multi-facet AppID not working in Chromium v40.x

Tags: security, google-chrome, fido-u2f

I use U2F to authenticate users to the web service.

When I deploy U2F with a single-facet AppID in the form of "https://example.com" everything works great. However, when I try providing multi-facet AppID to Chrome browser during the Yubico key registration or authentication, Chrome rejects the AppID immediately (I'm getting error code #2) instead of downloading the JSON file.

Question: is support for multi-facet AppID included in the current Chrome U2F extension (v0.9.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* like Chrome is not supporting the standardized way of listing facets (but instead supports another similar way). See [this bug report](https://github.com/google/u2f-ref-code/issues/27) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

A fix has been merged into Chromium:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471522

The fix will be available in Chrome 43.